# Rule of thumb for conventional oven baking vs. grilling kebabs (ground meat &

Tags: baking, meat, grilling, kebab

I am trying to cook two different ground meat as a kebab (I already had the preparation done for ground venison and ground lamb Adana kebabs). Most of the recipes I see online assumed grilling over charcoal, but since I am in an apartment in a city, I am trying to bake the kebabs using my conventional oven.

I wanted to see what the corresponding rule of thumb is for cooking time across different types of meat over a charcoal grill vs. a conventional oven:

i.e.,

```
                  Conventional Oven/Temperature     vs.          Charcoal grill
```

Time to cook:

Ground lamb

Ground venison

Ground beef

Lamb cubes

Beef Cubes

Chicken

etc.

I'd like to have some type of conversion between the conventional oven times vs. charcoal grill times. If there is a chart on how long to cook between a conventional oven vs. charcoal grill for different types of meat (as well as temperature setting), that would be great.

Comment: The answers will vary based on volume of the meat and temperature. For kebabs it will be under the grill/broiler at maximum setting for ~15 min. Charcoal doesn't have temperature settings as such, though you  could use a temp probe/scanner to get an estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to get a general comparison chart so I can see what oven temperature setting vs. grilling can apply to various types of meat. Is there a place where I can find this, or a rule of thumb I can apply on how long I can cook either ground meat or cubes of meat and what that would translate to when baking in the oven?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than normal oven baking, I usually put things under the broiler (grill, whatever your country calls top-only heat), on the highest temperature, with the rack set so the items are 1 to 2 inches (2.5 to 5 cm) from the heating element.  If it's a thick cut of meat, like a bottom round steak (for "london broil"), then you'll want to leave at least 2" (5cm) of space as it will plump up when it cooks

And then just cook until the top is browned to your liking, roll / flip them over, brown again, etc, until it's well browned.

And while this is going on, you'll want to leave the oven door slightly ajar.  This prevents the oven from warming up so much that the heating element shuts off, which means you're no longer getting radiant heat.  And you want to watch it, as things can go from brown to black in only a minute or two.

If they're not sufficiently cooked through at that point, then you can leave them in the middle of a low oven (maybe 300°F / 150°C) until they're cooked to your liking.

Comment: Door open/closed is likely to be brand/model-dependent. My last one said to always leave open, my current much more expensive one says to always close it.

Comment: @Tetsujin : I vaguely remember someone saying that it might be a function of electric vs. gas ... I'm used to using electric.  (non-fan assist, and it's probably 20 years old or so).  I guess if you don't know, try it with the door closed, and if you notice it shut off, then you know you'll need to leave the door ajar in the future.